# C++ errors and questions

Tags: c++

Pictures of the code and errors:
https://puu.sh/sPat1/da5b011ac6.png
https://puu.sh/sPavZ/ad81dc6386.png

Questions : This is a program that generates 600 numbers from 1 to 49 , 3 times. 1800 numbers total. How can I check through all the numbers I mean how many times 1 is included, 2 ,3 ,4 ,5 ,6 . . . 48, 49.. <- IN ONLY ONE OF THE ARRAYS a[100][6] for example.  Please help.

Comment: Please post the actual code and error *text* on Stack Overflow, not an image.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another array/vector with indexes from [0..49] and increment the desired index every time you meet a value in an original array:

```
int arr[100][6];
//fill it

int check[50];
for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    check[i] = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        check[arr[i][j]]++;

//now check has a list of occurences for 0, 1, 2, ..., 49
```

As for code style, I would suggest to go away from magic constants like 100, 50, and use something like

```
const int max_random = 50;
const int mat_width = 100;
const int mat_height = 6;
```

Also, for C++ the usage of std::vector is encouraged instead of usual arrays - STL is created just for the purpose of leaving most of the pointers/low-level operations under the hood.